# How can I have a single route map to different controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My current Rails 2 project has a couple of different resources, each of which needs to be accessible via root level permalinks (i.e. a user being accessible via http://domain.com/john and a group being accessible via http://domain.com/thehunters). I know in Rails 3 I could use a condition on the routes to have the permalinks route appropriately, however, routing conditions in Rails 2 are much more limited.

What's the best way for me to make this work? The best I can come up with is having a PermalinkController that then calls on the correct actions in the correct controllers, but this ends up very unDRY, slow, and brittle.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea altogether. If anything, those two URLs should be `http://domain.com/users/john` and `http://domain.com/groups/thehunters` - at first glance, there is no difference between the two URLs you gave. `thehunters` could just be another username. Try to be as RESTful as you can. URLs are important and should be easily understandable.

Comment: I'm working on a website targeted at your grandparents, and your grandparents probably don't care about RESTful design, but rather about ease of use. We've already had users complain about about not being able to get to a group page (because the weren't typing in "/groups/" before it. RESTful does not necessarily equal user friendly. Facebook figured this out: user pages and other type of pages are all in the same namespace at the root of the path.

Answer (score 0):

I think basically what you suggested is what needs to be done except for there is no reason to reroute to different controller.
Your "Permalink"Controller should accept the variable from the params, interpret that variable to determine which model to use and in turn decide which view to use with that model and render that view.

Comment: Unfortunately, that would involve sticking all of our logic (we want all of our actions, not just show, and including those from nested resources to work) from each of the other controllers inside one controller, separated by if statements. Seems ugly and hard to maintain, but it at least works.

Comment: Try to move as much logic as possible inside your models and only use controllers for fetching and routing data